# can I use using(var scope = new TransactionScope()) with Postgres?

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, transactions

I'm doing

```
using(var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
//lots of calls to sql server
scope.Complete();
}
```

and it works like a transaction

I would like to know if it is going to work the same with **postgres** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TransactionScope` eventually result in creation of concrete transaction object. In case of MS SQL it is [SqlTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.aspx), in case of postgres it might be [NpgsqlTransaction](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/docs/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlTransaction.html) or whatever you are using. So if you doubt, you always can create transaction explicitly and be sure.